# KeyEvent with Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm wanting to catch the event when the user turns the volume up and down using the phone's physical keys.

This is my code:

```
Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().onPreviewKeyEvent {keyEvent: KeyEvent ->
                        when(keyEvent.key) {

                            Key.VolumeUp -> {
                                Log.e("MainActivity", "volume up")

                                true
                            }

                            Key.VolumeDown -> {
                                Log.e("MainActivity", "volume down")

                                true
                            }

                            else -> true
                        }
                    },
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
```

it doesn't log anything.

Please help me, thank for your help!!!